# Parsing file but get a NullReference exception?

Tags: c#, parsing, streamreader

Sorry about the title, I honestly didn't know how to describe the problem there.
Anyway, here's my predicament. I'm currently parsing an info file. The "authors" and "dependencies" section of it is similar. However, the creators of the info files have the option to write theirs differently. It can be written like:

> ```
> "authors" : 
> [
>   "author1",
>   "author2"
> ],
> ```

or:

> ```
> "authors": ["author1", "author 2"],
> ```

I need to turn both of the styles into:

> ```
>  author1, author2
> ```

The file I'm trying to parse looks like this:

> ```
> -snip
> "authors": [
> "author1",
>  "author2",
>  "author3"
> -snip
> ```

I have been successful in parsing the second way authors write it. However, when I try to parse the first way, I get a NullReference exception. The exception details goes as follows:

> > System.NullReferenceException was unhandled by user code   HResult=-2147467261   Message=Object reference not set to an instance
> >     of an object.   Source=RKs Tool Kit   StackTrace:
> >            at RK_Tool_kit.ParseModInfo.getAuthors(String path) in C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\Programing\C# Projects\RK Mod Installer\RK Mod
> >     Installer\RK Mod Installer\ParseModInfo.cs:line 119
> >            at RK_Tool_kit.AddMods.txtbxAddMods_DragDrop(Object sender, DragEventArgs e) in C:\Users\Sam\Desktop\Programing\C# Projects\RK Mod
> >     Installer\RK Mod Installer\RK Mod Installer\AddMods.cs:line 85
> >            at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnDragDrop(DragEventArgs drgevent)
> >            at System.Windows.Forms.Control.System.Windows.Forms.IDropTarget.OnDragDrop(DragEventArgs
> >     drgEvent)
> >            at System.Windows.Forms.DropTarget.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IOleDropTarget.OleDrop(Object
> >     pDataObj, Int32 grfKeyState, POINTSTRUCT pt, Int32& pdwEffect)
> >     InnerException:

I'm at a loss here. Thanks so much in advance. Here is my code:

```
    public static string getAuthors(string path)
    {
         string line;

         using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path))
         {
             while (!sr.EndOfStream)
             {
                 line = sr.ReadLine();
                 if (line.Contains("author"))
                 {
                     //This detects if it is the second way the authors can write it
                     if (line.Contains("[") && line.Contains("]"))
                     {
                         line = line.Replace("\"authors\": ", "").Replace("\"authors\" : ", "").Replace("\"authorList\": ", "").Replace("\"authorList\" : ", "").Replace("[", "").Replace("]", "").Replace("\"", "").TrimStart(toTrim);
                         int Place = line.LastIndexOf(",");
                         string comma = ",";
                         line = line.Remove(Place, comma.Length).Insert(Place, "");
                         return line;
                     }
                     //This means the the author wrote it the first way. And the string "line" just says '"authors": [' so we want to read the line again.
                     else
                     {
                         line = sr.ReadLine();
                         line = line.Replace("\"", "").TrimStart(toTrim);

                         for (int i = 0; i < 101; i++)
                         {
                             //This checks to see if there is only one author in the array. If there is a comma, we want to read another line because there is another author.
                             if (line.Contains(","))
                             {
                                 //THIS RIGHT HERE throws the exception
                                 line = line + sr.ReadLine().Replace("\"", "").TrimStart(toTrim);
                             }
                             else
                             {
                                 break;
                             }
                         }

                         return line;
                     }
                 }
             }
         }

        return "N/A";
    }
```

Comment: On what line does the `NullReferenceException` occur?

Comment: it's in the code as a comment,

Comment: @TheGreatCO What Mike C. said.

Comment: Yeah, I missed it first time through.

Comment: Have you tried putting breakpoint on that line to see what *is* null?

Comment: @Matthew No. I'll give it a go.

Comment: @Matthew I'll get you the details in the main post once I get stack overflow to stop yelling at me saying my code isn't formatted right...

Comment: @DJKRAZE What will this change?

Comment: @Matthew There. Can you please take a look at it?

Comment: Is this data JSON, if so, you should just use a JSON parser instead of writing your own.  http://json.codeplex.com/ is a good one.  Other than that, I think @Lee has the right solution.

Comment: @Matthew I never thought of that. It could be JSON data, but doesn't use the JSON extension, if there even is one. In the meantime, I'll accept Lee's solution. Thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[StreamReader.ReadLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.io.streamreader.readline.aspx) returns null if the end of the stream has been reached, so you are probably getting a null line and trying to call `Replace("\"", "")` on it.

Comment: I originally thought that also, but that's not the case. I know for a fact there is something next. And, if the end of stream was reached, it would have just returned "N/A".

Comment: @user1522456 - You're checking for the end of the stream at the beginning of the `while` loop but then reading multiple lines from the reader without checking for null. `ReadLine` is the only method on that line that can return null. Try reading it into a temporary string and attaching a debugger when the exception is thrown so you can inspect it.